# Is it possible to print rgb colours in C

Tags: c, terminal

I want to print out the block character(█) as any rgb colour(#000000-#ffffff). I'm aware of the ANSI colours and the [ANSI 8-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#8-bit) however the colours are to limited for my use. How can I best achieve full RBG color range on terminal?

This will only be used for UNIX/UNIX like OS, there will be no windows use.

Comment: Please note that asking for library recommendations isn't [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (see point 3). With that said, there are special terminal programs which extend the number of colors available, you might want to search for other terminals rather than the standard terminals most commonly used in Linux installations. The character sequences to control them won't be portable to other terminal programs though.

Comment: `I'm aware of the ANSI colours and the ANSI 8-bit however the colours` did you read the next section on the wiki? It's about ANSI 24-bit colors...

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the question so it's not asking for a library, but askig how to achieve what is needed. Feel free to roll back or edit further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use a custom/non-standard terminal emulator, all eventual libraries will be based on the ANSI control sequences. If that is not sufficient for your use, you should consider making a gui application. Also as @KamilCuk pointed out in the comments, the ANSI colors are not limited to 8 bits but to 24 bits, which allows you to specify any (#000000-#ffffff) color.

If you are designing a command line UI, you should also keep in mind, that not all people use a "white font on black background" terminal color scheme. While you can achieve "cool" color effects with the 24 bit colors, I would encourage you to respect the users color scheme choice and stick to the 3 and 4 bit colors (described in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#3-bit_and_4-bit) section). If you do that, your command line program will be much more likely to look and work well even on terminals with a light colorscheme.